# Reducing the size of website increases the width

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I have YouTube-style header like css, when I reduce the size of my website, the width of my YouTube-style header increases and my icons extend beyond the boundaries of the site, but when trying same thing with https://m.youtube.com/
it does not increase its width no matter how small you make it, any idea on this ?
i dont want to use overflow:hidden; because when website size is reduced then it cuts out my icons, icons should still be visible like in youtube mobile version.

try it here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-icon-avatar-example-forked-exzhzj?file=/src/app.css&resolutionWidth=153&resolutionHeight=671

code:

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Avatar from "@material-ui/core/Avatar";
import NotificationsIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Notifications";
import MenuIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Menu";
import SearchIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Search";
import VideoCallIcon from "@material-ui/icons/VideoCall";
import AppsIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Apps";
import "./app.css";

export default function EmailAvatar() {
  return (
    <div className="box-container">
      <div className="header">
        <div className="header__left">
          <MenuIcon />
          {/* <img
            className="header__logo"
            src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e1/Logo_of_YouTube_%282015-2017%29.svg"
            alt=""
          /> */}
        </div>
        <div className="header__input">
          <input placeholder="Search" type="text" />
        </div>
        <div className="header__icons">
          <span title="Create">
            <VideoCallIcon className="header__icon" />
          </span>
          <span>
            <AppsIcon className="header__icon" />
          </span>

          <span title="Notifications">
            {" "}
            <NotificationsIcon className="header__icon" />
          </span>

          <Avatar
            alt="Remy Sharp"
            src="https://www.shutterstock.com/image-photo/skeptic-surprised-cat-thinking-dont-260nw-1905929728.jpg"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<EmailAvatar />, rootElement);
```

img of problem:

[image]

youtube mobile:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

overflow hidden add

```
.header {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: that makes it worse, i want to be able to make it as small as possible like in youtube and still should not increase its width and icons should not go out of site

Comment: updated: remove width and min-width add overflow:hidden;

Comment: overflow hidden just hides it and that icon still goes out

Answer (score 0):

Your header is inside another container, and has a sticky position
change this for your header class :

```
.header {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

Comment: if i do that then when i reduce size of website icons like cat and notification wont be visible

Comment: Because you are using static values inside the header elements, all of the values should be responsive to the view, use either (%) or (em)